# getting get-credentials requires edit permission error on gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to setup credentials for kubernetes on my local.

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials ***** --zone **** --project elo-project-267109
```

[image: error log]
This query works fine when I tried it from cloud shell, but I got this error when I tried run it from my terminal:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) get-credentials requires edit permission on elo-project-267109
```

I've tried this query from admin account as well as default service account also from new service account by assigning editor role and it still doesn't seem to work for me.

i am using macOs Mojave(10.14.6) and gcloud SDK version installed in my system is 274.0.1
[image: screeshot of version SDK]

i was able to resolve this issue on my local but i was actually trying to build a CI/CD from gitlab and the issue persists there, i have tried using gcloud(279.0.0) image version. [image]
[image: error log gitlab]

i am new to both gitlab and gcloud. i am trying to build CI/CD pipeline for the first time.

Comment: Have you tried running `gcloud init` or `gcloud auth login` to authenticate again with the same IAM user that is used in Cloud Shell?

Comment: do `gcloud auth list` to see which user is logged in on your terminal. You are likely not logged in or authenticated properly in your terminal. Cloud shell will login by default with the same google user account you used to log into console.cloud.google.com

Comment: I have tried doing both of these multiple times

Comment: Which version of Cloud SDK do you use? What OS do you use? Could you update your question with full output of suggested commands?

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza updated with screeshots

Comment: Thanks! It's slightly outdated. Try to update it to the latest 279.0.0 and if you still have a problem after that try to delete Cloud SDK and install again.

Comment: hi @SerhiiRohoza, it worked on my local with the updated gcloud version. but i was trying to build a CI/CD pipeline from gitlab, and the same error happened. i have tried to use the latest image for gcloud but still it failed with the same error

Comment: it worked on gitlab as well. thanks @SerhiiRohoza

Comment: @Nitish Kumar Could you share what was the cause of your problem? Was it connected to outdated Cloud SDK? It'll be helpful for other community members. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza it turned out to be the image version mismatch issue on gitlab

Comment: @NitishKumar I am running the same problem. Could you specify how you solved the problem?

Comment: Check the version of cloud SDK you are using and if it is not the latest one try updating the version

Answer (score 0):

Do `gcloud auth list` to see which account are you logged into.

You need to login with the account which has the correct credentials to access the action that you're trying to perform.

To set the gcloud account: `gcloud config set account <ACCOUNT>`

Answer (score 0):

It's turned out to be the image version mismatch issue on GitLab.